# jQuery Address Plugin - Not allowing loading ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, deep-linking

I am trying to test the jQuery Address Plugin and it seems to not allow ajax to work in the change function.

I am using:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {
    $('#content').load(event.value+' #content');
    $.address.title(event.value);
});
$('a').click(function() {
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

While I can use event.value for other things, it just does not seem to let the .load() function work.  Even trying a static URL in .load() does nothing.  Is something in the plugin preventing this?  I thought this was the point of the plugin!

Comment: I guess you have to use  `$.address.value()` instead of `event.value`

Comment: That is not helping.  The ajax functions are still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using event.pathNames instead, I think you cant get this to work because you are not replacing the "/" from the value.  Using event.pathNames  you dont have to do that....

```
$('#content').load(event.pathNames+'.htm #content');
```